# how to override the already overridden class

Tags: magento

Some other custom module has already overridden a third party module's class file(SOME BLOG EXTENSION). After researching I came to know that you can only override once.

Now I also need to override that same core file in my own custom module. As it's already overridden how can accomplish that?

I can not use events because that third party module is not firing any events.

Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: I Found the problem and the fix. 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579383/overriding-class-first-to-second-working-but-overriding-second-to-third-not-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the problem and the fix. The link is in comment. Sorry for some reason I could post the link here. It goes into comments automatically. So I am writing here incase anyone needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple chain the different modules... For instance:

A is the original class, B and C are two modules trying to override A. Simple set-up this:

B extends A, C extends B. If you have functions that are both used you can simple call the parent function so they can add their magic.

Comment: So if B and C are overriding A then which one will run first?

Comment: The class that is overridden the latest.

Comment: No it's not working. Please check my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579383/overriding-class-first-to-second-working-but-overriding-second-to-third-not-work